# Multiselection of recycler view inner containers

Tags: java, android-recyclerview

[image]

This is my recyclerview adapter. I am inflating views. Now I want to select the containers in each view. They are working fine but when I scroll down to the list the selection gone missing. Please help me to store the selection containers on each view. Thanks

[image]

Here is my onBind Method of recyclerviewAdapter;

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final NewProductsView holder, final int position) {
        final int posi = position;
        final Product product = products.get(position);
        if (positiono.contains(position)) {
            holder.cat_con.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            int i = positiono.indexOf(position);
            holder.cat.setText(categories.get(i).getName());
        } else {
            holder.cat_con.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.product_name.setText(product.getName());
        holder.price1.setText("SAR " + product.getSwDrycleanPrice());
        holder.price2.setText("SAR " + product.getSwWashingPrice());
        holder.price3.setText("SAR " + product.getSwPress());
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(product.isSelected());
        holder.checkBox.setTag(product);

        if (product.isSelected()) {
            holder.checkBox.setSelected(product.isSelected());
        } else {
            holder.checkBox.setSelected(!product.isSelected());
        }


        if (product.isSeriver1()) {
            setColored(posi, holder);
        }else {
            setColorTransparent(holder);
        }

        if (product.isSeriver2()) {
            setColored(posi, holder);
        }else {
            setColorTransparent(holder);
        }

        if (product.isSeriver3()) {
            setColored(posi, holder);
        }else {
            setColorTransparent(holder);
        }

        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                Product emp = (Product) cb.getTag();

                emp.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                products.get(posi).setSelected(cb.isChecked());

                Toast.makeText(
                        v.getContext(),
                        "Selected Employees: " + cb.getText() + " is "
                                + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        holder.service_con1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!holder.isFav) {
                    product.setSeriver1(true);
                    products.get(posi).setSeriver1(true);
                    products.get(posi).setSeriver2(false);
                    products.get(posi).setSeriver3(false);
                    setColor(holder, 0);
                    holder.isFav = true;
                } else {
                    holder.isFav = false;
                }
            }
        });

        holder.service_con2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!holder.isFav) {
                    product.setSeriver2(true);
                    products.get(posi).setSeriver1(false);
                    products.get(posi).setSeriver2(true);
                    products.get(posi).setSeriver3(false);
                    setColor(holder, 1);
                    holder.isFav = true;
                } else {
                    holder.isFav = false;
                }
            }

        });

        holder.service_con3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!holder.isFav) {
                    product.setSeriver3(true);
                    products.get(posi).setSeriver1(false);
                    products.get(posi).setSeriver2(false);
                    products.get(posi).setSeriver3(true);
                    setColor(holder, 2);
                    holder.isFav = true;
                } else {
                    holder.isFav = false;
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

this is the setColor method:

```
public void setColor(NewProductsView holder, int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                holder.service1.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                holder.price1.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                holder.service_con1.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

                holder.service2.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                holder.price2.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                holder.service_con2.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

                holder.service3.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                holder.price3.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                holder.service_con3.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

                break;
            case 1:
                holder.service1.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                holder.price1.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                holder.service_con1.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

                holder.service2.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                holder.price2.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                holder.service_con2.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

                holder.service3.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                holder.price3.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                holder.service_con3.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

                break;
            case 2:
                holder.service1.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                holder.price1.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                holder.service_con1.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

                holder.service2.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                holder.price2.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                holder.service_con2.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

                holder.service3.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                holder.price3.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                holder.service_con3.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice screenshots, but... where is the code?

Comment: Please check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing directly setTextColor on any view, you should update that in the arraylist that is bound to the adapter.

after changing any value , user `notifyDataSetChanged();` and it will work correct.

Reason: Always when you scroll a recyclerview , it recycle the views every time when they come into focus.

Example:
Whenever you set a new color using `setColor()` method, save that color in arraylist too and set that dynamically in `onBindViewHolder` method.

Let me know if i misunderstood.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the help notifyDataSetChanged(); not working correctly, my list size is 33, while scrolling the selected container position appears on other view. Can you help with it

Comment: did you try using if else instead of switch case . in many cases in recyclerview this thing happen because of this thing also . just try it and let me know if the issue is still same.
also must use else statement with if .

Comment: Hey, thanks! I resolved it. Notifydatasetchanged() helped.